# Horizontal position bug on user page in IE8

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

During few last days I am observing a bug with IE8 on Windows XP on a user info page:
[image: screenshot]
Other stackexchange groups I tested work well with IE8. There is no such bug in Firefox.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this bug in IE8. I don't have XP anymore, only Vista. Can anyone else reproduce this bug?

Comment: XP is build-in in my netbook, sorry. I may guess, that horizontal scrollbar should not be visible at all neither on user page nor on main and other pages of cstheory, but it does in IE8. Appearance and shape of the scroll bar demonstrate, that IE8 calculated horizontal size of page as extremely big and on user page it is only moved right “a bit” in comparison with that huge width.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I can reproduce the same bug by opening the [user page](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/4915/alex-qubeat) with IE 9 on Windows 7 and explicitly turning on the [compatibility view](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view) of IE 9.  The bug does not appear with the default setting (without clicking the compatibility view icon) with IE 9.  I do not have IE 8.

Comment: So do I now - I clicked "compatibility view" button on IE8 and page is really corrected

Comment: Right now: no more bug! Should I check something?

Answer (score 1):

That is weird. Maybe a post on meta.SE ?